# No value set for `/apps/metacity/general/theme'

Tags: 16.10, metacity

Whenever I open a terminal I get the following message:

```
No value set for `/apps/metacity/general/theme'
```

It doesn't stop me from using my system, but the message is still there. I'm curious as to what is causing it and how I get rid of it.

The error has appeared ever since I installed `gnome-session-flashback`. Note that I'm running metacity, not Unity.

Comment: Does that happen if you try with new user? It seems that something tries to read setting from GConf. Metacity for long time does not use GConf so that setting does not exist there...

Comment: @muktupavels - Yes, it does. It happens in every session that uses metacity as a desktop environment.